# Fourier transform of the logarithm in three dimensions

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, analytic-continuation

I would like to evaluate the (inverse) Fourier transform of $\log(\mathbf q^2+a^2)$ on $\mathbb R^3$, i.e. formally
$$
\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\log(\mathbf q^2+a^2)e^{i\mathbf q\cdot \mathbf x}\,,
$$
where $a$ is a positive real constant and $d^3q$ stands for $dq_1 dq_2 dq_3$.

Comment: where is the d thingy in your integral? it's undefined without it. $\int f(q,a,d)$ makes no sense but for example $\int f(q,a,d)dq$ or $\int f(q,a,d) da$ does

Comment: @mathreadler $d^3q$ is supposed to be a shorthand notation for $dq_1 dq_2 dq_3$

Comment: ok, maybe we should add it in a remark so it also becomes understandable to those who don't know of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote
$$
\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \log(\mathbf q^2+a^2) e^{i\mathbf q \cdot \mathbf x}=\mathcal F^{-1}\big[ \log(\mathbf q^2+a^2) \big] \equiv T(\mathbf x)\,.
$$
Using the properties of the Fourier transform,
$$\begin{aligned}
-\mathbf x^2 T(\mathbf x)&=\mathcal F^{-1}\big[\partial_{\mathbf q}^2 \log(\mathbf q^2+a^2)  \big] \\
&= 2 \mathcal F^{-1}\big[ (\mathbf q^2+a^2)^{-1}\big]+4a^2\mathcal F^{-1}\big[(\mathbf q^{2}+a^2)^{-2}\big]\\
&=(2-2a \partial_a)\mathcal F^{-1}\big[ (\mathbf q^2+a^2)^{-1}\big]\,.
\end{aligned}$$
Now, the inverse Fourier transform of $(\mathbf q^2+a^2)^{-1}$ can be calculated directly: denoting $r\equiv |\mathbf x|$
$$
\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{i\mathbf q \cdot \mathbf x}}{q^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{2\pi^2r}\int_0^\infty \frac{q\, \sin(qr)}{q^2+a^2} dq =-\frac{1}{4\pi^2 r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{iqr}}{q^2+r^2}dq=\frac{e^{-ar}}{4\pi r}\,,
$$
where the last integral can be calculated by standard contour integration methods.
Substituting back, we find
$$
-r^2 T(r)= \frac{e^{-ar}}{2\pi r}+\frac{a e^{-ar}}{2\pi}
$$
whose general solution is
$$
T(r)=-\frac{e^{-ar}}{2\pi r^3}-\frac{a e^{-ar}}{2\pi r^2}+C\delta(r^2)\,,
$$
where $1/r^3$ and $1/r^2$ are understood as derivatives of the principal value PV$(1/r)$ and $C$ is a constant. However, in $\mathbb R^{3}$, the distribution $\delta(r^2)$ is identically zero:
$$
\langle \delta(\mathbf x^2), \varphi(\mathbf x)\rangle = \int d\varphi\, d\theta \,\sin\theta\, r^2 \delta(r^2) \varphi(\mathbf x)=0\,,
$$
so the final answer is independent of $C$:
$$\boxed{
T(r)=-\frac{e^{-ar}}{2\pi r^3}-\frac{a e^{-ar}}{2\pi r^2}
}\,.
$$

Comment: I know this is an old post but hopefully someone will still see this, how did you in your inverse Fourier transform get the $4a^2$ since I get $4q^2$ but is there a special Fourier transformation property or am I missing some algebra?

Comment: I think I used that $\mathbf q^2/(\mathbf q^2+a^2)^2=1/(\mathbf q^2+a^2)-a^2/(\mathbf q^2+a^2)^2$ (add and subtract $a^2$ in the numerator), but I need to double check...